# Touchscreen keyboard for kiosk

Tags: c#, .net, touchscreen, kiosk

I wrote a simple c# windows forms application (.net, in visual studios 2012) for a mouse-controlled keyboard for use in a desktop application. Ultimately, I want to have a keyboard form that can be used on a touchscreen in a kiosk-like setting.

My question: can I expect the desktop app to work "as is" on a touchscreen?  My specific concern is whether I can reasonably expect the mouse-click events to intercept touch events on the touchscreen, or whether I should a priori consider importing certain libraries and/or bind events other than "Click". I would simply test it myself but I don't have access rights now to a touchscreen device on which I can run the app.

Comment: Yes, you can expect it to work. Normal touch events (not including gestures) will be handled via same `Click` event as mouse click.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I expect the desktop app to work "as is" on a touchscreen?

Yes, it's down to the hardware to translate a "touch" to a click. You can write more advanced apps which target touch screen devices specifically e.g. swiping/pinching etc. However, if yours is just a basic app with buttons it should all work the same on a touch screen.